# The 30-days restriction behind Health-Connect data while deprecating Google Fit APIs

Tags: android, healthconnect

So I'm talking about Health-Connect Android SDK integration. There is a restrcition from Android side to read user's data up-to max 30 days.

You can see this [link](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-connect/develop/read-data#read-restriction). I want to understand that one side Google Fit APIs are already depreacted and it will be shutdown in 2024 and another side Health-Connect is not giving option to read entire user history, then what is the purpose to built the app?

What if users want to see the average of their 1 year or 6 month data together? Can anyone tell me what is the reason behind this restriction?

Comment: I think you're misreading it.  Once they give you permission, the permission is good for 30 days.  Then they have to reauthorize you.  Not that you can only read 30 days of data.

Comment: @GabeSechan I think OP has it correct. The link even has an example. My belief is that as the Health Connect app is still marked Beta, they are checking usage. Given the privacy focus of the new system Google maybe thinking: newly installed App C can collect their own data and need App A and App B data to show benefits so App C only needs a limited set of prior to install data and picked 30 days as a cutoff. Once approved App C is free to collect it owns data and ask for data from App A & B to update App C's records.

Comment: I was wandering about this too. The 30-days-limit after the first authorization by the user encourages to NOT use Health Connect as the data-store, but to save everything in my own database in case the user uninstalls and later reinstalls my app.
At least that's how I understand it and implement it.

Comment: It's not about first authorization only, even though user kept app for 2 months, I won't be able to read data more than 30 days. But I want to show entire history.